# GPO result test

Tags: group-policy

Running gpresult,from computer policy we are getting computer components access denied.
We try :
nslookup %USERDNSDOMAIN%

net view %USERDNSDOMAIN%

cd \%USERDNSDOMAIN%\SYSVOL\%USERDNSDOMAIN%\

and check file permissions in folders: Policies and scripts

delete registry key: 
reg delete HKLM\SOFTWARE\Policies /f
reg delete HKCU\Software\Policies /f

delete folder:
RD /S /Q %windir%\System32\GroupPolicy

Comment: Can you be a little more clear on the problem? Are you saying that you see "access denied" under Component Status under Computer Configuration Summary or are you saying that you see Denied GPOs under Group Policy Objects?

Answer (score 0):

GPRESULT needs to be run from an elevated command prompt, to get the machine policies.